# IReadOnlyList<T> and setter

Tags: c#

What does it mean when property of the attribute is a `IReadOnlyList` but it has a setter? My confusion is that if the List is read only, then why do we need setter?

```
public IReadOnlyList<string> FilteredProductId { get; set; }
```

Comment: list is read only but not the field

Comment: To resolve your particular potential misunderstanding of properties we need more details. Could you please [edit] post to explain why `public string Id {get;set;}` does not bring the same question for you (or maybe it does)? Note that `string` is essentially read only list of characters matching your question very closely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that it is odd that they protected the **contents** of `FilteredProductId`, but not the instane itself. I would have expected at least a private setter. This is the kind of setup that is there to prevent the person *using* that code from doing stuff he is not supposed to.

What does it mean? Well, FilteredProductId is not fully protected. However, it might not be nesseary to have *full* protection (instance and contents). Just the lack of a `Add()` function is a serious protection against accidental modificaiton. Nobody can add anything to the list by accident.

And creating a new Read Only Collection and assing it there? That is involed too. Not the kind of thing most people do by *accident* either. So the protection might actually be enough.

Comment: In other words, the class needs to know when you change the list via the setter. If you could get the current list, then manipulate it, the class would not be able to tell.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman It is not about being able to tell something happened, as getting help from the Compiler to avoid it happening in the first place. Fun fact: `List<T>` actually implements this interface. So any odd list could be assigned there. But as you would only be working with a `ReadOnlyList<T>` from there, no further addition can happen (without casting it back to List). | There is no way for a class to prevent being replaced. This is something the code using the class has to do.

Comment: There's nothing stopping the setter from replacing the list to ensure it's readonly...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman The list already is readonly, as all you get is the lits ReadOnlyCollection Interface.